# how to add publishing profile to a new sln in vs2012?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

I have read the publishing profiles have replaced WDP

but I cannot find decent tutorial

how to add and modify `pubxml` file to my project

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you right-click a project and select **Publish**, you get the **Publish Web** wizard.  Using this to create a profile (you don't have to actually publish in order to create a profile) creates the .pubxml, and on the first step of the wizard you can use the **Manage Profiles** button to rename or delete profiles.  Profiles are created in a PublishProfiles folder under Properties.  See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398069.aspx

Comment: pretty strange but I cannot create NEW profiles once I defined one. Is it possible?

Comment: @Adi please see my answer in order to add a new profile once you have already created one.

Answer (score 32):

In order to create a **new profile** once you have already defined one, you have to open the "Publish" window (righ click on the project), click on the "Profile" tab and select the `<New...>` option from the drop-down list; this will create a new `pubxml` file (see screenshot).
It's a bit tricky to find and I wonder why they didn't put a "New" button on the "Manage profiles" window.

[image]

Comment: meanwhile I found this option myself, but +1 for pointing it out

Comment: thanks..."It's a bit tricky to find and I wonder why they didn't put a "New" button on the "Manage profiles" window." Agrre with you @StockReak

Comment: there is no option in my visual studio like that, publish website option  is not like that as yours, how am i going to get those options ? @StockBreak