# how to add files in web.config transformation process?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-config

I am having a website developed in Visual Studio 2012.
The web.config is currently containing following files in its transformation:
- web.Debug.config
- web.Release.config

I have recently added a new build configuration (named as "Staging") in my project. How can I create a "web.Staging.config" transformation file?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

There are two ways for the web.config transform files to be generated within VS:

1. If you have a web application project, *Right-click on web.config and choose Add Config Transform.*  This will add **any** config transforms that are missing from your project based on **build configurations** (i.e. if you have Production and Staging build configs, both will get a transform added).

   - This method is not supported for Website projects as they do not support multiple build configurations.
2. In either web project type, *right click on a publish profile (.pubxml) and choose Add Config Transform*.  This will add a new config transform for that profile only.

   - This requires VS2012 Update 2 or the Azure SDK 2.0 for VS2010 (*I think*).
   - In a web site project, the new transform file will *not* be nested under web.config as VS doesn't support that behavior.  Just look for it in the root folder.

Comment: In a Website project type, find the _.pubxml_ under the /App_Data/PublishProfiles/ subdirectory. VS2012 creates this when you set up a Publish Web Site project (by right clicking the Web Site in Solution Explorer).

Comment: See these instructions for creating a profile.  No need to click the "Publish" button at the end of the wizard if you are manually publishing the application.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441692/how-to-add-publishing-profile-to-a-new-sln-in-vs2012

Comment: See spadelives answer if you right click but do not see "Add Config Transform" as an option

Comment: Right clicking on web.config does not show any **Add Config Transform** command.

Answer (score 52):

IN VS 2012:

1. Go to Build->Configuration Manager
2. Click on the Active solutions configuration and select "New".
3. Enter the name of your new configuration and click Save.
4. Right click on your Web.config file and select Add Config Transform.

Your new transform file will be automatically created.

Comment: No such option appears when right clicking *web.config* for me.

Comment: Years later I know, but you won't see this option if you *already have* a web config transform for all of the existing Build configurations - i.e. if you have Debug and Realease build configs, and you already have Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config transforms, you won't see the option - you would have to add a *new* build configuration, hence the instruction in the answer above!

Comment: Ran into this issue when adding a new project to a solution that had other configurations. Eventually realized that the profile didn't exist on my project, only at the solution level and within the old existing projects. So you may need to double check your project is not defaulting to another configuration when added.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me, thanks! I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: This is not supported to web project type.

Answer (score 6):

You need to first install the [Configure Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GolanAvraham.ConfigurationTransform) extension [**Extensions** -> **Manage Extensions** -> **Online** section] to see the option when right-clicking your `web.{environment}.config` files.

Comment: This answer is the one that actually helped me! Thanks a lot! I'm using VS2019, Community Ed.