# I don't see the Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config files on my web.config after upgrading my project to VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-config, config-transformation

I just upgraded a Web Site project from VS2010 to VS2012 and I was looking into figuring out how to do what I used to do in the DeploymentPackage projects.  There is a lot of good questions and answers I've read through on stackoverflow and I know what to do once I am able to find the files I need.  For some reason my web.config doesn't have the two files underneath it (Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config).  I've installed the Web Platform Installer stuff and created my profile.  I also created a custom configuration for deployment but I still am unable to see these files get created so that I can start changing some of my web.config settings on deploy time.  Does anybody know if there's some setting/trick to get these files to show up in a migrated project?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't see the files web.debug.config or web.release.config beneath the web.config file it could be because they are hidden. In the solution explorer panel if you click "show all files" they should appear.

Comment: This was my issue as well in V2019, though I don't know why these were hidden in the project but no other one I've ever worked on.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a post here:  [how to add files in web.config transformation process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542421/how-to-add-files-in-web-config-transformation-process)
In your "App Data" folder you'll find your publish profiles you created and can right click on them to add a config transform file.