# How to add a nested Web.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I tried adding a new web.config file to my asp.net app (I went through right click on the project -> add -> Web Configuration File).
However at the Solution Explorer the newly added file is not nested under Web.config. Any idea?
See image -
I would like Web.Staging.config to be nested just as Web.Release.config:
[image: Solution Explorer]
(Assume VS 2012 or 2013).

Comment: why do you want it like that??

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add files in web.config transformation process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542421/how-to-add-files-in-web-config-transformation-process)

Comment: It was indeed a duplicate of the above question. Sorry, couldn't find it. However the answer that worked for me is not the accepted one but [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16825153/145599).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx).

Specifically:

> To add configuration specific transform file (e.g. Web.Staging.Config) you can right click the original web.config file and click the context menu command “Add Config Transforms”

Comment: Thanks. I accepted this answer although the problem was that "Add Config Transform" option is disabled until you add a new build configuration. However in the blog post you sent there was another link that described that as well.

Answer (score 25):

If all you want is nesting, you could just open your csproj file in a text editor and change this:

```
<None Include="Web.Staging.config" />
```

to this:

```
<None Include="Web.Staging.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

Comment: This works fine for local Project files. However if you have a config file linked from a Solution folder as a link, there is no error but the DependentUpon tag does not render the item as a child in Solution Explorer. It's really a non-issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also currently use the File Nesting tool

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting