# Web config transformation in visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, continuous-deployment, web.config-transform

I am using visual studio 2012 and I am finding it difficult to add web.config files for diff environment. I looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542421/how-to-add-files-in-web-config-transformation-process) and tried right clicking on *.pubxml* file and *choose add config transform* option. After I do this, system adds web.simplePublish.config file which **I am not able to rename using visual studio**.

[image]

If I rename the file using windows explorer, the file is not listed under web.config tree in the solution.

[image]

**What is the right way to add web.config files for various environments in Visual Studio 2012.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [SlowCheetah - XML Transforms plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) of visual studio to create web.config files for diff environment.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to modify the *.csproj then find out the filename before you rename it and to revise the filename that you using windows explorer.
or you can just try to add a new tag into *.csproj

```
  <ItemGroup>
<Content Include="..\default.licenseheader">
  <Link>default.licenseheader</Link>
</Content>
<Content Include="packages.config" />
<None Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\xxxx.pubxml" />
<None Include="Web.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="Web.Release.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
<None Include="Web.SimplePublish.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</None>
```

The other way that you can use Configuration Manager at your visual studio please refer the following link [Add an Additional](http://greglevenhagen.com/asp-net-4-web-config-and-net-4-app-config-transformations/)

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. But this sounds more like a work around. There must a straight forward way. Let me wait for few more replies.

Comment: @Brown_Dynamite I have already update the answer and provide you another way to reach your requirement.