# Unable to create additional project configurations in VS2015 Professional for a Web Site

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2015

I am new to building C# Web Page and have setup a Razor3 Web Site.  When the site is created there is a web.config and web.debug.config.  In our environment, there are differences between datasources in development and production, so I would like to create a "Release" configuration.

Unfortunately, when I go to the configuration manager, the "Create new project configurations" check box is greyed out.

https://www.evernote.com/l/AJTBgHVhubFDpoTO_OkazT3RbKwyXvx_NSo.jpg

So far I haven't been able to find how to create this new config and only have the ability to launch the site as though it is in debug mode.

How do I create this additional configuration similar to a web application can be setup?

Comment: right click on the web.config file => add config transform.

Comment: @sebastian-schulz When I right click web config, I don't see config transform.  I am seeing: https://www.evernote.com/l/AJQEm9dOgExFV72ntQGvXmem8oEQ6QFlnDA

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542421/how-to-add-files-in-web-config-transformation-process

Comment: there is an extra addon https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/579d3a78-3bdd-497c-bc21-aa6e6abbc859