# How to use different web.config file for different publish profiles in ASP .NET Core 2.0 project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have URL rewrite rules configured for production IIS application pool that do not work in the development IIS application pool (notably HTTP to HTTPS redirection).

What I have:

- `web.production.config` for production
- `web.config` (for development AND local IIS Express)
- Two publish profiles (development and production).

What I need:

- `web.production.config` to be published with the production publish profile.
- `web.config` to be published with the development publish profile AND used by the local IIS express for local debugging.

What I currently do:

1. Exclude both files from being published.
2. Copy the `web.production.config` file manually after deployment, renaming it to web.config on the server.

How can I automate this? The `<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment />` property in pubxml does not suppress the need for a renaming of the file after deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use web.config/IIS to achieve your redirects etc. then I would recommend using [Web Config Transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542421/how-to-add-files-in-web-config-transformation-process#16826106) for help on how to add a transform for each of your environments. Web config transforms are easy to create/maintain and are automated as part of the publish process.

However, I would say that with .net Core there are many options for [URL rewriting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) or [enforcing HTTPS redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) from middleware which allow you to explicitly switch on the current environment. These tend to be preferred over reliance on IIS.

Comment: I switched to ASP.Net Core rewriting middleware, removing the dependency on IIS. Thank you!