# MS Visual Studio Add several config files

Tags: visual-studio-2012, app-config

I'm adding a Project (console application) to an already existing web project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.  I'm trying to add a number of config files depending on environment application is run in...the files highlighted in the red box in the picture below

[image]

I've had a look online and it suggests right clicking on the App.Config file and selecting 'Add Config Transform', however, this option does not appear.  I also [read you can't 'Add Config Transform' for web applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826106/205233).  However, the Project I'm trying to add these additional config files to is a console application.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the multiple config files is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, VS 2012 only did transforms for web.config.  So when we had the same problem we solved it by adding the SlowCheetah Nuget package, which adds the ability to auto create transforms for each of your builds, for app.configs as well.

Have a look at this post as well, which discusses this:
[App.Config Transformation for projects which are not Web Projects in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004210/app-config-transformation-for-projects-which-are-not-web-projects-in-visual-stud)

Hope this helps!